# Does methods should manipulate lazy collections?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm wondering if method should manipulate lazy collections?
This is example:

```
public class Person {
    // lazy collection
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Friend> friends;

   public Friend findFriend(String name) {
      //pseudo code
      return friends.findByName(name);
   }
}
```

Does findFriend is correct method? When I use it in transactional service method then will be Ok but someone may use it outside transaction and then exception occurs.

Is it bad practice to create methods which manipulate on lazy collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good interface makes it easy to do the right thing but hard to do the wrong thing.

In your example any client code has to know about that precondition that you mentioned. That is not wrong by default, but makes it easy to cause problems that will only show up at runtime.

The minimum thing here could be to improve the names of this class /method to at least make that precondition more "explicit".